# MySql to Sequelize Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Sequelize to represent some MySQL tables.
However I'm running into a few issues with foreign keys and constraints.

I can't seem to work out how to correctly use them.

Here is the MySql of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `pw` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastchannel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `texture` longblob,
  `last_active` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `users_id` (`server_id`,`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_name` (`server_id`,`name`),
  KEY `users_channel` (`server_id`,`lastchannel`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_server_del` FOREIGN KEY (`server_id`) REFERENCES `servers` (`server_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

And here is my work in progress for the Sequelize:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Users = sequelize.define('users', {

    server_id:   {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
    user_id:     {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
    name:        {type: Sequelize.STRING(255), defaultValue: null},
    pw:          {type: Sequelize.STRING(128), defaultValue: null},
    lastchannel: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11), defaultValue: null},
    texture:     Sequelize.BLOB,
    last_active: {type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW, onUpdate: Sequelize.NOW}

  }, {
  indexes: [
    {
      name: 'users_id',
      unique: true,
      fields: ['server_id', 'user_id']
    },
    {
      name: 'users_name',
      unique: true,
      fields: ['server_id', 'name']
    },
    {
      name: 'users_channel',
      fields: ['server_id', 'lastchannel']
    },
  ]
});

  Users.removeAttribute('id');

  return Users;
};
```

As you can see, I think I have the core properties complete and as they should be as well as the unique keys (I think). Where I run into issues is the line:

```
CONSTRAINT `users_server_del` FOREIGN KEY (`server_id`) REFERENCES `servers` (`server_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Can anyone give me any pointers into how to represent this line best?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You can define foreign key constraints in the model associations.  See the Relations / Associations section of the docs: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/

Comment: I added the following, however it doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect. var Servers = sequelize.import('./servers'); 
Users.belongsTo(Servers, {foreignKey: 'server_id', targetKey: 'server_id', constraints: true});

Comment: What error do you get?  Can you post the model definition of the servers table?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto).

It's pretty handy for exporting an existing table structure as a `js` model from the command line:

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d database_name -h host -u username -p 3306 -x my_password -e mysql
```

*Disclaimer*: I haven't used it with constraints, but looking over the project's tests it seems to have good foreign key support.

Comment: Wow, that was fast!